# Can We Prove that the Area Within a Parabola is Always Less than the Area Not Above the Parabola?

Tags: integration, functions, quadratics, area

Recently, I thought of the following question. Take the standard parabola function, y = x^2:

[image]

**Is it possible to mathematically show that the area above the area within the parabola (i.e. the shaded area in red) is always less than the area not-within the parabola?**

[image]

Looking at a visual picture, this makes sense. If you were to enumerate the 4 quadrants from the counterclockwise direction, the parabola does not cover any quadrants 3 and 4 all together. Furthermore, there area regions in quadrant 1 and quadrant 2 that are not covered by the parabola. Thus, logically - for this picture that I have drawn, it seems like the area within the parabola must be less than the area that is not-within the parabola.

But in math, this is not a sufficient way to prove a statement whatsoever!

I first tried to quantify the above logic: Suppose the square grid that I drew has an area of 1: this means that the coordinates on the extremities of the square are `(-0.5,0.5), (0.5,0.5), (0.5,-0.5), (-0.5, -0.5).`

If you were to integrate this parabola from x = -0.5 to x = 0.5, the area would be: `2* ((0.5^3/3) -  (-0.5^3/3)) = 0.166`. The area of the quadrants 3 and 4 are 0.5. This means that the area within the parabola is `1 - (0.166 + 0.5) =  0 .344`, and the area not-within the parabola is 0.666.

Thus, as expected - it would appear that for this isolated case that I drew, the area contained within the parabola is in fact less than the area not-within the parabola.

**But could this now be proven for** *all cases*?

Would proof by induction be useful for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just integrate the parabola from $-x$ to $x$.  You will discover that that value is smaller than the area of the corresponding rectangle, which will be $2x^3$.  (In fact, the area below the curve is exactly a third of the area of the rectangle.)

Comment: Sorry I can't follow the meaning for the problem... If I choose the rectangle totally inside the parabola, will this relation not be held? could you specify the constraints of the rectangle and the parabola?

Answer (score 1):

Not known where the limit horizontal lines are initially drawn, area depends on it.

Ignoring quadrants 3 and 4 considering top half of unit square only,small square has area under curve:

$$ A=\int_0^\frac12 x^2 dx=\dfrac{1}{24} $$

Yellow area= $\dfrac{1}{12} $

White area = $\dfrac12 - \dfrac{1}{12}=\dfrac{5}{12}$ not true.

So the bottom border should be drawn even farther below, by an amount upto the line $ y= -(\dfrac{5}{12}-\dfrac{1}{12})=-\dfrac{1}{3}.$

[image]

Comment: wow! this is so cool! do you know if this counts as a "mathematical proof"? thanks!

Comment: Please see my edit. Area calculation is quite straightforward. If there is any way to improve it, shall edit/ modify my answer.